# Getting error [object Object] in AppComponent_Host ngfactory js in angular 8 app

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I m trying to run this offical sample [angular app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular) from Microsoft Identity platform (which uses MSAL library to authenticate Azure AD users) and getting the following error. I am unable to figure out exactly which package or version is causing this error and how to go about fixing it. Any ideas?

> VM61 AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:6 ERROR Error: [object Object]
>       at viewWrappedDebugError (VM21 vendor.js:84484)
>       at callWithDebugContext (VM21 vendor.js:95180)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (VM21 vendor.js:94680)
>       at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (VM21 vendor.js:85367)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (VM21 vendor.js:83089)
>       at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.bootstrap (VM21 vendor.js:91935)
>       at VM21 vendor.js:91657
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap (VM21 vendor.js:91657)
>       at VM21 vendor.js:91625

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try deleting node_modules and do npm install again.

Comment: @AakashGarg that's exactly what I did and it did not make any difference

Comment: what command you are using to run the application?

Comment: and did you follow setup steps mentioned on github url you told?

Comment: I have downloaded the source and yes using `npm install` and `ng serve --port 4202 -o` commands and yes I did add the values for the placeholders like tenenatId, clientId etc

Comment: Inside MsalModule.forRoot ?

Comment: @AakashGarg yes

Comment: can we have that config? as we can't set it up without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with the Msal Configuration. I was setting authority value just the Tenant Id **Guid** like below

```
 MsalModule.forRoot({
  auth: {
    clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx-bxxxxx-4xxxxxx-9xxxxx-xxxxcf',
    authority: 'xxxxxxxxxx-dddxxxxx-ffffxxxxx-8xxxxx-xxxxcs',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4202/',
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
  },
},
{
  popUp: !isIE,
  consentScopes: [
    'user.read',
    'openid',
    'profile',
  ],
  unprotectedResources: [],
  protectedResourceMap: [
    ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
  ],
  extraQueryParameters: {}
})
```

The authority value should have been `authority(or Cloud_Instance_Id)/tenantId` e.g.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx-dddxxxxx-ffffxxxxx-8xxxxx-xxxxcs/

I wish if there would have been a better error/exception shown from angular or Msal library to give us a pointer that its an issue with the Msal configuration.

Hope it helps some one facing the same issue

Comment: Thanks rumi.. it indeed helped me.. I agree could have been little bit elaborate on the exception.. you saved my time! :)